# 6502 assembly and representation of addresses

Tags: assembly, indexing, addressing, 6502

I am trying to understand this kind of addressing mode in assembly 6502.

for instance we have in program this kind of instructions:

we know that ''text'' label is under $2000-high byte is 20, low byte is 00
in accumulator we have number 30.
Now the first question is: What happened when I type `STA $80.`
Does it mean that the whole address where we store accumulator is 0080?
Now let say we put under $80 00 number  and under $81 number 20. Y is zero.
Now why when I use this:

```
sta ($80),y
```

I am getting address 2000? How is that happening? Under 0080 we have only 00(byte) not the whole address(2 bytes) 2000. I know that ($80) means that we go to the addresses pointed by $80. But we stored there only 00 not the whole address 2000. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On 6502 addresses are 16 bit. The `STA $80` example used zero page addressing, which automatically implies the top 8 bits are zero, thus the full address being `$0080`. The indirect addressing fetches the top 8 bits from the next memory cell, since each cell is 1 byte and you need 2 bytes for the address.

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like `STA ($nn),y`, the CPU will read the byte at `$nn` *and the byte at `$nn+1`,* reverse them, and concatenate them into a 16-bit address, then write to *the resulting address*. It's a bit confusing to say the least, but it's working exactly as intended. Since you stored $20 at address $81, the lookup ends up evaluating to `STA $2000`. Had you stored $50 into address $81 it would have been $5000.

Comment: Reverse them from which initial order?  Surely it just uses the 2 bytes as a little-endian integer address, same as it uses for absolute addresses in machine code.  https://www.masswerk.at/6502/6502_instruction_set.html describes the addressing modes (including zero-page indirection) and instructions.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502 says it's little-endian.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was basically trying to say what you said here but I couldn't think of a good way to phrase it.